# Serializing a datetime

Tags: c++, time, c++11

What would be the best way to perform binary serialization of a date/time pair?

My best guess so far is to store the number of seconds since the epoch, as returned by the POSIX time() and mktime() functions, and then translate it back to "human readable" structures using localtime() upon retrieval.

Please note that timestamps will be stored and retrieved by computers in various timezones.

Comment: C or C++? They are distinct languages and I would use different approaches in each.

Comment: You could combine `boost::date_time` with ` boost::serialization`. Or if you don't want to use Boost, the C++11 standard library provides   a `chrono` header, which defines an `std::chrono::duration` and `std::chrono::timepoint` that can be easily serialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends some on what data, exactly, you're interested in:

- Do you need sub-second precision?  POSIX `time_t` generally doesn't provide that, obviously, unless you use some sort of floating point type (which can introduce its own issues).  Other languages' and libraries' time formats (such as JavaScript's and Java's) use milliseconds-since-a-fixed-date instead of seconds-since-a-fixed-epoch to address this.
- If timestamps will be stored and retrieved across time zones, then using a format that's defined as relative to an epoch (like POSIX `time_t` or a [JavaScript Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description)) is probably better than storing local time + a time zone.
- If you need to know the original time zone, then you'll need to store that too.
- Because of the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), if you use something like POSIX `time_t`, you'll want to store it as a 64-bit number, not a 32-bit number.  (Even if you store it as a 64-bit number, keep in mind that your C runtime's `mktime` and `localtime` implementations may not support 64-bit `time_t` values.)

Regarding the year 2038 problem in particular:  I don't know of any POSIX APIs that are guaranteed to handle it.  If you want a library that's guaranteed to handle it, you might be better off using something like `boost::date_time`.  The [Project 2038 FAQ](http://maul.deepsky.com/~merovech/2038.html#What_operating_systems_and_platforms_are_affected_by_it) has information on testing your C runtime for 2038 support.  According to that page, modern 64-bit Linux systems should not be affected.  Recent versions of Visual C++ are also not affected.  ([See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).)  Even if your libraries don't currently support 64-bit `time_t` values, you can serialize a 64-bit int and cast it to 32 bits to process it; that way your on-disk data structures will at least be compliant, and your libraries will hopefully be updated before 2038 becomes a problem.

Comment: No, I don't need subsecond precision, but the year 2038 is something I would like to take proper care of... what options do I have? is time_t 64-bit long on 64-bit systems, or are there other POSIX APIs to handle this?

Comment: @cyberguijarro - I added some details on year 2038.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that timestamps will be stored and retrieved by computers in various timezones.

And do you need that time zone to be stored as well? Are you interested in the *local* date and time when it was stored, or just the *instant* in time?

Basically, work out what information is important to you, and make sure you store that.

Comment: No, the timezone from which the datetime was stored is not important, as timezone is a user-defined setting. The actual, universal, instant is what matters here.

Comment: @cyberguijarro: Right, in that case "seconds since the unix epoch" is entirely reasonable (assuming that's the precision you've got the data in to start with). Make sure you document it very explicitly :)

Answer (score 0):

You've answered yourself.  a computer-understandable time value that gets translated to a human-readable format on demand, depending on the local human's situation (ie daylight time, time zone, 24hour, etc) is the best. Its also small to store.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to interface with your binary type. If always using POSIX functions then sure, a time_t value would be fine. On Windows you'll need to convert it to their format to get a date out of that. Always save the binary value as a UTC of course, don't apply any offsets to this original value.

Another way (not the fastest) would be to store a string and not be tied to any one function library. Of course, if you know for sure that a binary value of 1345739726 was created using a POSIX call then you can do the conversion if you move that value to a Windows system. A string format just removes any question as to what point in time is represented.
string sTime = "Year:Month:MonthDay:WeekDay:Hour:Mintue:Second:Daylight:GMTOffset"